# When accessing localhost IIS asks for username and password

Tags: windows, iis

I have installed IIS on `Windows XP SP3`. When I want to access localhost from my browser the authentication window appears and asks for user name and password. Anonymous access is enabled for `IUSR_` user and this user has full control permission on `wwwroot` folder. Any help is appreciated in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You've set your web site up to use Integrated Windows (NTLM) Authentication, which is supported by default in IE but not in Firefox. Firefox requires you to permit NTLM on a site-by-site basis.

[This page](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/Firefox%20asks%20for%20user%20name%20and%20password%20on%20internal%20sites) explains how to enable NTLM and remove the login boxes in Firefox.

Basically, you need to type `about:config` in the address bar and add the hostname to the list of comma-separated values on the `network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris` setting.

Let's say you have two sites that you want to enable NTLM authentication on: http://www.foo.com/ and http://www.bar.com/. You would need to set `network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris` to `www.foo.com, www.bar.com`.

If you want your site to be accessible to anonymous users, you need to make sure that your IUSR_xxx account has at least read permission to the files that your web site is serving at the file system level. You can do this via Windows Explorer. I think you also need to grant list permission on the parent directories.

Comment: I'm new to IIS. How can I permit NTLM?

Comment: It looks like you have already done this. To configure it in IIS 5 (I think you'll be running this seeing as you're using XP), you go to the properties for your web site, click on the Security tab, click a button to open the Authentication Methods dialogue box, then tick the "Integrated Windows Authentication" checkbox.

Comment: When "Integrated Windows Authentication" checkbox is checked it asks for authentication. But when I uncheck it "The page cannot be displayed" message appears on the borwser.

Comment: See the last paragraph that I just added to the answer.

Comment: As I mentioned in the question this user has fullcontrol permission on wwwroot directodry

Comment: Hmmm... it's hard to diagnose what might be going wrong without seeing what's going on on your machine. Make sure that the IUSR account has permission to access the parent directories. And of course the permissions need to be inherited downwards through the file system, so that would be worth checking as well.

Comment: Another thing: is the web server error related to security (i.e. an HTTP 4xx error)? If it's a 5xx error, the problem might be occurring in the web application code.

Comment: I'm just trying to access localhost. This is the error: Error Type:
Microsoft VBScript runtime (0x800A0046)
Permission denied: 'GetObject'
/localstart.asp, line 40